# How to use feature_column v2 in Tensorflow (TF-Ranking)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using TF-Ranking to train a recommendation engine. I have encountered a problem that seems to be a version incompatibility issue concerning `tf.feature_column` API.

The short version of my question is: What is a v2 feature column (TF 2.0?) (see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/31fc134816cc4974a46a11e7bb2df0066d0a88f0/tensorflow_ranking/python/feature.py#L92) for instance) and how can I ensure that my feature columns are treated as v2, while I'm still using TF 1.14.

Here is the details:

I'm unable to shorten my code sufficiently to provide a reproducible example. But I will try to describe the problem in words.

TF Version: 1.14
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I initialy had two features in my model, `user` and `item`, both sparse categorical features which were wrapped in their own `tf.feature_column.embedding_column`. I was able to use the `train_and_evaluate` method of the `Estimator` and export the model for serving.

Then I added a new feature `curr_item` which is only present during prediction (as a context feature). This shares the embeddings with `item`. So now I have a `tf.feature_column.shared_embedding_columns` which wraps both `item` and `current_item`.

Now calling `train_and_evaluate` results in the  following error (shortened messages):

> ValueError: Could not load all requested variables from checkpoint. Please make sure your model_fn does not expect variables that were not saved in the checkpoint. 
>   Key input_layer/user_embedding/embedding_weights not found in checkpoint

Note that calling `train` method only works fine. My understanding is that once it gets to evaluation, it tries to load the variables from the checkpoint, but that variable doesn't exist. I did a little debugging and found the reason:

When `encode_listwise_features` is called during training (which in turn calls `encode_features`) all features (`user` and `item`) are "V2" (not sure what that means) and so the following if statement holds:

https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/31fc134816cc4974a46a11e7bb2df0066d0a88f0/tensorflow_ranking/python/feature.py#L92

and both variables are named with an `encoding_layer` prefix (scope name?):

> encoding_layer/user_embedding/embedding_weights
>   encoding_layer/item_embedding/embedding_weights

But when I call the same function for all three features (a little confused wether this is in eval or predict mode), some of these are not "V2" and we end up in the else part of the above condition which calls `input_layer` direcetly and variables are named using `input_layer` prefix. Now TF is trying to restore

> input_layer/user_embedding/embedding_weights

from the check-point, but that name doesn't exist in the checkpoint, because it was called

> encoding_layer/user_embedding/embedding_weights

in training.

So:

1) How can I ensure that all my features are treated as v2 at all stages? I tried using `tf.compat.v2.feature_column` but that didn't help. There is already a ToDo note above that if statement for this.
2) Can the `encode_feature` be modified to avoid this situation? e.g. raise an exception with a helpful message?